# Visualize target graph for Ant

Tags: java, ant

I have to analyze an Ant build file, which includes other Ant build files, calls targets from additional Ant files which themselves import and call other files.

Is there a way to get a list or tree of all called ant targets (starting from one target specified in the main build file)?

I think about using XML parsing, searching for antcall, ant and import statements, but this will become tricky as a lot of properties are set and a lot of different properties files are used which influence the structure of the paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Grand](https://ant-grand.github.io/Grand/grand.html) has a nice visualisation gui and is easy to use (if you do not have spaces in your windows directory structure -- my fault).

Comment: I wish it were so easy. :(
`no main manifest attribute, in grand-1.9.7.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Vizant](http://vizant.sourceforge.net/), an Ant task for visualizing buildfiles.

The following example uses Vizant to generate a Graphviz DOT file. The `dot` command then takes the DOT file as input and it outputs a PNG image...

```xml
<taskdef name="vizant" classname="net.sourceforge.vizant.Vizant" classpath=vizant.jar"/>
<vizant antfile="build.xml" outfile="workflow.dot"/>
<exec executable="dot">
    <arg value="-Tpng"/>
    <arg value="workflow.dot"/>
    <arg value="-o"/>
    <arg value="workflow.png"/>
</exec>
```